# Earth connection lines

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I've been looking for the solution on the Internet and the only thing I found is this tutorial for Blender 2.79 with Animation Nodes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEYI4lnOprY&ab_channel=WiresoulStudio

I need to generate only these connection lines, perhaps in Geometry Nodes. The connection between points can be random (points will be generated from continents mesh).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What have you tried, what has failed and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Do you want those connection lines be random or come from some data? In the latter case you need to somehow encode them in the way that geometry nodes can parse, e.g. write a Python script that loads a file with coordinates and creates a mesh with edges, where the vertices of the edges are starts and ends of the paths. Then in geometry nodes you can import this mesh, convert edges to curves, convert them to bezier, convert handles to auto, and position handles on nearest surface normals (maybe scaled down or up a bit, depending on the size of the Earth and desired effect).